# Determine particular webview page loaded in android

Tags: android, html, webview, title

We've multiple html pages (for example abc.com/abc.html,  abc.com/xyz.html) to load in single WebView class of android.
Now, I want to achieve that once any particular page loaded successfully, I can identify particular page and behalf of that I can some display message in native app. 
I was using `webview.getTitle()` to identify, but it's getting change some time from webview page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare link(URL) before load a particulate page in to WebView

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              /* compare your URL from here*/

                updateUrl(url);
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
//                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, onPageFinished(view, url), we get this callback in success and error case both. We'll have to that message in case of success only.

Answer (score 1):

If this is only the `title` that you want to track, you can implement a `WebChromeClient` and listen to the event `ReceivedTitle` in the method `ReceivedTitle()`

you can look at: 
[WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html)

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
         onReceivedTitle(WebView webview, String title){
             // put your code here

         }
    }
)
```

#### EDIT

- You are dealing with javascript so you have to enable it in your web view:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private WebView myWebView;
  private TextView myTextView;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
      myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.local/changetitle/");
      myTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView);
      WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
          @Override
          public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
              super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
              myTextView.setText(title);
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  }
- here is a sample webpage a tested it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>First Title</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="myFunction();">
  <div id="text">No changes</div>
  <script>
            var i=27
            function myFunction() {
    
                document.title=""+i;
             var x = document.getElementById("text");   // because title won't dispay in the body
             x.innerText = "title : "+document.title;   
             i++;
             setTimeout(myFunction,3000);
            }
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No, looks you get my question wrong. I already handing using title, but that is not trusted because that is not fix. So wanted some hidden content to read on finish.

Comment: I Tried, it works but you have to do some stuff when dealing with hybrid apps.  Enable javascript (dynamics website uses client script or node.js). I'll change my answer